# How to place a vertical line between two divs?

Tags: html, css

How to place a vertical line between two `div` elements?

[image: want to design like this using html and css]

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container .column {
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vr {
  border-left: 2px dotted black;
  width: 2px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-container mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="column">Karvat group was established in Mumbai.</div>
    <div class="vr "></div>
    <div class="column2 bg-alt box arrow-left ml-15 "> 1952</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, what do you mean by "blade"?

Comment: sorry for the mistake

Comment: You still haven't shared any code

Comment: <div>

        <div class="flex-container   mt-3 d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="column">Karvat group was established in Mumbai.</div>
            <div class="vr "></div>
            <div class="column2 bg-alt box arrow-left ml-15 "> 1952</div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: .flex-container {
                                        display: -webkit-flex;
                                        /* Safari */
                                        display: flex;
                                        /* Standard syntax */
                                        margin: 0 auto;
                                        text-align: center;
                                    }

Comment: .flex-container .column {
                                        width: 320px;
                                        text-align: center;
                                    }

Comment: .vr {
                                        border-left: 2px dotted black;
                                        width: 2px;
                                        margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
                                        height: 200px;
                                    }

Comment: Please edit you question and add all the details in that which you've mentioned as separate comment. @DevPatil

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code for it, You can also take some help from online codepen's https://codepen.io/havardob/pen/dyKoOjX

```css
.stepper{
  height: 400px;
  width: 1px;
  border-right: 2px dashed black;
  position: relative;
}
.stepper:before,
.stepper:after
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: -7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #fff;
}
.stepper:after{
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rough way of getting this done.

### HTML

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>2017</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>2016</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a background color */
body {
  background-color: #474e5d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* Container around content */
.container {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

/* The circles on the timeline */
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -17px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Place the container to the left */
.left {
  left: 0;
}

/* Place the container to the right */
.right {
  left: 50%;
}

/* Add arrows to the left container (pointing right) */
.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}

/* Add arrows to the right container (pointing left) */
.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.right::after {
  left: -16px;
}

/* The actual content */
.content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

/* Media queries - Responsive timeline on screens less than 600px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/* Place the timelime to the left */
  .timeline::after {
    left: 31px;
  }

/* Full-width containers */
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }

/* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
  .container::before {
    left: 60px;
    border: medium solid white;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  }

/* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
  .left::after, .right::after {
    left: 15px;
  }

/* Make all right containers behave like the left ones */
  .right {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I want text on both side of the line in the same line.